# How to modulate an AudioParam with a LFO in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

How can i modulate any of the AudioParams in Web Audio API, for example gain value of the GainNode using a Low Frequency Oscillator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not saving your actual nodes, just the value - so when you try to connect to oscillator.frequency, you're passing an integer value (400 - the frequency you saved in the node).  Try http://jsfiddle.net/GCSEq/6/ - this stores the nodes, and properly routes to the AudioParam.

```
this.oscillator = context.createOscillator();
this.gain = context.createGainNode();
```

and
    osctest2.play(osctest.oscillator.frequency , 1000);

(You were getting an error in the console.)

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'start' on 'OscillatorNode': cannot call start more than once. " when using the start and stop functions more than once. Is there a way to stop and start the oscillator after stopping it? I'm trying to make a sequencer.

Comment: I forgot to call start() on my LFO, your answer reminded me ;)

Answer (score 10):

https://coderwall.com/p/h1jnmg

```
var saw = context.createOscillator(),
      sine = context.createOscillator(),
      sineGain = context.createGainNode();

//set up our oscillator types
saw.type = saw.SAWTOOTH;
sine.type = sine.SINE;

//set the amplitude of the modulation
sineGain.gain.value = 10;

//connect the dots
sine.connect(sineGain);
sineGain.connect(saw.frequency);
```

Comment: but im trying to make an easy to use object constructor with good routing capabilities. it seems like i can not pass the output from the second instant to the first one. take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/GCSEq/2/

Comment: Well, no - you can't directly put